# R ftpUplad error: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a data.frame called 'ftp_test' via ftpUpload command

```
library(RCurl)
ftpUpload("Localfile.html", "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/Destination.html")
```

and am getting an error:

> Error in file(what, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(what, "rb") :
>   cannot open file 'ftp_test': No such file or directory

Could anyone tell me what is the issue here? Can I actually use data.frame and upload from r global environment ?

If I can't use the data.frame is there any workaround?

Many thanks,

Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is, that you are trying to send an R object with an file transfer protocol. Since you are saving it there, you have to tell how to save it. A workaround is to save it as a file, upload it and then delete it on your local afterwards. Also saving as R.History is fine, but you need to transfer the R object to a file in some way. This example is used with an open ftp sever (uploads get deleted immediately, but you can try if it works)

```
filename="test.csv"
write.csv(df, file=filename)
#use your path to the csv file here instead of ".~/test.csv", you can check with getwd()
ftpUpload("~/test.csv", paste("ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/",filename, sep=""))

file.remove(filename)
```

Also make sure your server is running. You can try your code with the open ftp server.